# Datepicker en Bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap, datepicker

Estoy utilizando un código que encontré [aquí](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) para hacer un Datepicker (necesito dos, quiero discriminar por fechas unas consultas). Soy bastante nuevo en el desarrollo web, este es mi segundo proyecto importante, así que probablemente sea algo sencillo, pero me estoy comiendo la cabeza.

La cosa es que, cuando coloco el Datepicker en la página, se me muestra de manera correcta, sin embargo no funciona el botón que debería abrir el calendario y la hora. [image: Este es el botón]

Sé que debe ser algo relacionado con el código JS, ya que es en lo que menos experticia tengo, pero mi pregunta es el qué puede estar fallando para que no se abra de la manera que se debe.

Anexo mi código. De todas maneras si tienen algún consejo que darme será bien recibido
`

```
  <div class="starter-template">
  <div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class='col-sm-6'>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
        });
    </script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class='col-sm-6'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                    <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
            });
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Espero que te sirva :)

Comment: Puede ser una solucion aunque no exactamente, tambien busco que se pueda determinar la hora. Me funciono, pero me gustaria algo como el link que anexe

Comment: @GilbertoGuerra jeje si exactamente ando buscando una solucion :)

Comment: Muchas gracias :)

Comment: @GilbertoGuerra listo mira las modificaciones :)

Comment: Meeee funcionoooo!!! Muchas gracias :)

Comment: @GilbertoGuerra de nada si algo me sigues contando, acierta mi respuesta como correcta quedo muy agradecido contigo :)

Comment: Listo, cualquier duda te comento, soy nuevo en esto pero quiero aprender. Muchas gracias :)

Comment: como haría para que sea solo hora o fecha?

Comment: Buenas tardes, de lujo los cdn para el datetimepicker, solo quisiera saber cómo cambiar el idioma, segun yo es con `locale: 'es'` pero me arroja un error. :(